# React Native : Adding TextInput to NavigatorIOS header

Tags: react-native

Looking for any possibility of adding  to Navigation header.
All I need is a search area on the header.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a NavigatorIOS based solution, but hopefully you'll still find it helpful...
https://github.com/darkrishabh/ReactNativeSearchRouter

[image]